# Why do I fail to authenticate during initialization of the gitlab database - postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, redis, gitlab, archlinux

Fail to Initialize Gitlab DB, Due to Authentication Error.

- I want to have a Gitlab server on my local machine.
- I've been following the Arch Linux wiki instructions.
- I am running Manjaro.
- Gitlab, Redis & Postgresql were installed via Software Manager on Manjaro.
- Got all three services running - Postgresql, Redis & Gitlab-Gitaly.
- Attempted to "Initialize Gitlab database" with the following terminal command: 
  su - gitlab -s /bin/sh -c "cd '/usr/share/webapps/gitlab'; bundle-2.5 exec rake gitlab:setup RAILS_ENV=production"
- Prompted for Password:
- "Failed Authentication", despite the password matching the /etc/webapps/gitlab/database.yml file configs

Setup Init Command in Terminal, per Arch Linux Wiki:

su - gitlab -s /bin/sh -c "cd '/usr/share/webapps/gitlab'; bundle-2.5 exec rake gitlab:setup RAILS_ENV=production"